# Creating variables using loops or lists. Dynamic Loops are bad?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, list-comprehension

So i've looked through stackoverflow and feel that very similar questions have been asked, however I wasn't able to quite tailor those answers to my problem (sorry!).

From other threads, what I have gathered is that
 1) dynamic loops are bad
 2) list comprehension or dictionaries might help me?

What I want to end up with

```
grant1 = median(df.query('income < 25000')['grant']
grant2 = median(df.query('income > 25000 and income < 50000')['grant']
grant3 = median(df.query('income > 50000 and income < 75000')['grant']
grant4 = ...
grant5 = ...

funding1 = median(df.query('income < 25000')['funding']
funding2 = median(df.query('income > 25000 and income < 50000')['funding']
funding3 = median(df.query('income > 50000 and income < 75000')['funding']
funding4 = ...
funding5= ...
```

Sort of what I want to do

```
source = ['grant', 'funding']
for x in source:
    x1 = median(df.query('income < 25000')['x']
    x2 = median(df.query('income > 25000 and income < 50000')['x']
    x3 = ....
    x4 = .....
```

Any suggestions, or confusions regarding what I am trying to do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Although you never mentioned this (?), it looks a lot like you're using `pandas`, in which case there are some better ways to address this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch a variables that you want to assign to, where the names might look like these: grant0, funding97, grant42, grant26, funding27

So instead of having seperate variables, put the data all together into one variable that stores them like this:

```
source = {'grant': [], 'funding': []'}
```

So instead of accessing the data from the variable `grant0`, you can do `source['grant'][0]`. As another example, instead of using `funding97`, use `source['funding'][97]`

---

If I understand your question correctly, this may be what you want:

```
income_brackets = [(0, 25000), (25000, 50000)]
source = {'grant': [], 'funding': []}

#Hard to understand one-liner
#source = {key: [median(df.query('income > {} and income < {}'.format(lower, upper))[key]) for lower, upper in income_brackets] for key in source}

#Easy to understand three-liner
for lower, upper in income_brackets:
    for key in source:
        source[key].append(median(df.query('income > {} and income < {}'.format(lower, upper))[key]))
```

---

How list comprehensions work:

```
>>> foo = []
>>> for i in range(10):
        foo.append(i)
>>> foo
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> bar = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> bar
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Dictionary comprehensions work similar to list comprehensions, except you have key value pairs.

---

Step-by-step explanation of my solution using the interpreter:

```
>>> income_brackets = [(0, 25000), (25000, 50000)]
>>> source = {'grant': [], 'funding': []}
>>> for lower, upper in income_brackets:
        print(lower, upper)
0 25000
25000 50000
>>> for lower, upper in income_brackets:
        for key in source:
            print(lower, upper, key)
0 25000 grant
0 25000 funding
25000 50000 grant
25000 50000 funding
>>> for lower, upper in income_brackets:
        for key in source:
            source[key].append(5)
>>> source
{'grant': [5, 5], 'funding': [5, 5]}
>>> source['grant'][0]
5
>>> source['grant'][1]
5
>>> source['funding'][0]
5
>>> source['funding'][1]
5
```

Comment: hmm. thanks for responding! this might be a silly question, but how would I then assign each variable in a list the value of median(df.query(...))

Comment: Scorpion_God, I appreciate your suggestions and confirmation that lists or dictionaries should be used. However (and the reason I was not able to figure this out from previous questions), is that I wasn't sure how to use them to efficiently assign the value
    median(df.query(...))
to each variable (aka: grant0 or grant1, etc)

Comment: @As3adTintin have a look at my answer again.

Comment: @As3adTintin: Don't use separate variables here.

Comment: @Scorpion_God

I'm new to python so it's going to take me a little to look over your answer, but I'll let you know how it goes and thanks for the input!

Comment: @As3adTintin what does `median(df.query(...))` return? A dictionary?

Comment: @Scorpion_God The list comprehension example is cool, however we actually don't end up using constant increases in income.

I'm still working on getting my `median(df.query(...))` values to link up with your list or dictionary examples - I feel like that is where the solution lies.

oh, sorry that was really ambiguous. the `median(df.query(...))` just returns a number. It is the median of the grant or funding limited to the given income bracket.

Comment: @As3adTintin sorry your parentheses are wrong. What does `df.query(...)` return?

Comment: @Scorpion_God ahhh I always forget those last parentheses... my apologies.

`df.query(...)` queries a DataFrame from the pandas library. So lets see... it would return a DataFrame with 1 column and the number of rows equal to the number of cases in the data. does that make sense?

Comment: @As3adTintin so you can access it like a dictionary? Have a look at the bottom of my answer, I think that may be what you want.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Ooo I don't fully  understand that yet but it looks promising. I'll check it out and get back here. Thanks

Comment: @As3adTintin edited again to (hopefully) help you understand more.

Comment: @Scorpion_God Oh thanks for the dictionary explanation. I think i followed most of what you wrote, however when I run what you suggested, `source` only results in the median for the `(50000, 750000)` income bracket:

`{'grant': 52450, 'funding': 4550}`.  Perhaps I did not understand the df.query properly? or maybe I left something out?

Comment: @As3adTintin what was it supposed to result in?

Comment: I think i may be having some success with `source[key].append({key: [median(df.query('income > {} and income < {}'.format(lower, upper))[key]) for lower, upper in income_brackets] for key in source})`

Comment: @As3adTintin yes my previous version had some problems. That one should work.

Comment: @Scorpion_God I'm hoping to receive 3 medians for grant and 3 for funding.

Now `source` results in:
`{'grant': [{'grant: [58352, 57441, 52450], 'funding': [3337, 3450, 4550]}], 'funding': []}`

I am not sure why the last `'funding'` is in there, however calling `source['grant']` removes the last `'funding'`. 

Now do you have a suggestions on how to output just one number (ie: 58352)?... something like `source['grant']['grant'][0]`...

Comment: @As3adTintin what does `df.query('income > 0 and income < 25000')['grant']` return? And see my answer, I rearranged it and added explanation on how to access data from the `source` variable.

Comment: @Scorpion_God

Ah your updated answer helped so much and I finally have the answer I am looking for. Thanks so much for your help and walking me through they python!

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with "dynamic loops"? From the point of view of code reuse, your latter approach is much more elegant:

```
source = ['grant', 'funding']
result = []

for x in source:
  r = []
  r.append(median(df.query('income < 25000')[x])
  r.append(median(df.query('income > 25000 and income < 50000')[x])
  r.append(median(df.query('income > 50000 and income < 75000')[x])
  # ...
  result.append(r)
```

I am not altogether sure what you are attempting to do.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that does work, thank you (I'll probably use this if I can't figure out scorpion_god's answer). A lot of other posts strongly discouraged dynamic loops. Here is one, for example [link](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Thanks for the help though, it may very well be the answer I end up using.

Comment: It's not the loop that's bad, it's creating a variable by modifying the dict returned by `globals` that's bad. You are simply just creating a list of values based on `source`.

Comment: This becomes unwieldy with lots of income brackets.